# Why does my quicksort crash with large, reverse-sorted arrays?

Tags: c, recursion, quicksort

I'm learning C and I tried out a recursive quicksort algorithm. At small input sizes, it works as expected; with random generated arrays it had no problems with all tested sizes (up to 100,000). With an descending array, it somehow breaks (Windows gives me a message, that the program has stopped working) at a certain array size (32,506).  Is there any error in my code (for example any wrong memory allocation - I'm not sure if I got this right) or does C have a limit in recursive calls or anything else?

Edit:
I know that my Quicksort implementation is rather naive and that it behaves terribly with this sort of Input, but I didn’t expect it to crash.

I am using GCC with MinGW on the command prompt on Windows 10. I’m not sure how to find out what happens exactly because I’m not really getting any specified error message despite of Windows telling me that my program has stopped working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int partition(int *a, int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo; int j = hi+1; int v,t;
    v = a[lo]; //partition element
    while (1) {
        while (a[++i] < v) {if (i == hi) break;}
        while (v < a[--j]) {if (j == lo) break;}
        if (i >= j) break;
        t = a[j]; a[j] = a[i]; a[i]= t; //swap
    }
    t = a[lo]; a[lo] = a[j]; a[j]= t;//swap
    return j;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int lo, int hi) {
    int j;
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    j = partition(a, lo, hi);
    quicksort(a, lo, j-1);
    quicksort(a, j+1, hi);
}

int main()  {
    int len;
    for (len = 32000;len < 40000;len+=100) {
        printf("New Arr with len = %d\n",len);
        int *arr;
        arr = (int*) calloc(len,sizeof(int));
        int j;
        //create descending Array
        for (j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            arr[j] = len-j;
        }
        printf("start sorting\n");
        quicksort(arr,0,len-1);
        free(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Does the error mention stack overflow when the program stops? Just asking because a typical problem with recursive programs is stack overflow.

Comment: `calloc` can fail.

Comment: This may help http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257002/what-makes-for-a-bad-case-for-quick-sort

Comment: A descending array is the worst-case input for "ascending" quicksort with a first-element pivot; it's where it has quadratic complexity, and you're very likely to recurse too deeply. You need a different pivot-selection method.

Comment: Run it with the debugger and then tell us what exactly is displayed when the problem arrives.

Comment: If indeed @molbdnilo is right about recursion depth being the problem (which is very plausible), then an alternative to changing pivot selection is to switch to a half-recursive algorithm.  That is, instead of sorting both sub-partitions recursively, sort the smaller one recursively, but just loop back to sort the larger one.  That will still have quadratic run time in unfavorable cases, but it will have logarithmic recursion depth and overhead in all cases.

Comment: Run successfully with multiple `calloc()/free()` as coded or single `calloc()/free()` outside of the loop. The function `quicksort()` is called up to 79599 times for each loop.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, when you say "just loop back", do you mean to say that `quicksort()` should make the two recursive `quicksort()` calls in smallest-first order, and you can then lean on optimizer settings to eliminate the tail-call?  Edit: just realised; of course you can eliminate the tail-call by hand, recursive -> iterative.  Doh!

Comment: @TobySpeight, yes, "eliminate the tail-call by hand" is pretty good description of what I was talking about.  Do not, however, overlook the detail that you must ensure it is the *smaller* sub-partition that is sorted recursively.  That's what ensures the logarithmic stack depth and overhead.

Comment: @John - I've expanded that idea into an answer.  I had to make some improvements to `partition()` to get it to run in an acceptable time, but eliminating the recursion of the larger subset improved the stack usage considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, your code fails at much larger sizes (c. 370,000 elements).  You are likely running into a platform limit (probably limits to recursion depth due to stack overflow).  Without the exact error message, it's hard to be sure, of course.

Your input set is likely a pathological case for your implementation - see [What makes for a bad case for quick sort?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/257002)

You can reduce the recursion depth by a better choice of pivot - a common technique is to take the median of the first, central and last elements.  Something like this:

```
int v0 = a[lo], v1 = a[(lo+hi+1)/2], v2 = a[hi];
/* pivot: median of v0,v1,v2 */
int v = v0 < v1 ? v1 < v2 ? v1 : v0 < v2 ? v2 : v0 : v0 < v2 ? v0 : v1 < v2 ? v2 : v1;
```

You can also reduce the recursion depth by recursing only for the smaller of the partitions, and using iteration to process the larger one.  You may be able to get your compiler's tail-call eliminator to convert the recursion to iteration, but if that doesn't work, you'll need to write it yourself.  Something like:

```
void quicksort(int a[], int lo, int hi) {
    while (lo < hi) {
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
        if (j - lo < hi -j) {
            quicksort(a, lo, j-1);
            lo = j+1;
        } else {
            quicksort(a, j+1, hi);
            hi = j-1;
        }
    }
}
```

With the above changes, I can sort arrays of over a billion elements without crashing (I had to make some performance improvements - see below - and even then, it took 17 seconds).

You may also want to return early when you find a sub-array is already sorted.  I'll leave that as an exercise.

---

P.S. A couple of issues in your `main()`:

You don't test the result of `calloc()` - and you probably should be using `malloc()` instead, as you will write every element anyway:

```
int *arr = malloc(len * sizeof *arr);
if (!arr) return fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed\n"), EXIT_FAILURE;
```

---

### Full listing

Here's the code I ended up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int partition(int *a, int i, int j) {
    int v0 = a[i], v1 = a[(i+j+1)/2], v2 = a[j];
    /* pivot: median of v0,v1,v2 */
    int v = v0 < v1 ? v1 < v2 ? v1 : v0 < v2 ? v2 : v0 : v0 < v2 ? v0 : v1 < v2 ? v2 : v1;
    while (i < j) {
        while (a[i] < v && ++i < j)
            ;
        while (v < a[j] && i < --j)
            ;
        int t = a[j]; a[j] = a[i]; a[i]= t; //swap
    }
    /* i == j; that's where the pivot belongs */
    a[i] = v;
    return j;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int lo, int hi) {
    while (lo < hi) {
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
        if (j - lo < hi -j) {
            quicksort(a, lo, j-1);
            lo = j+1;
        } else {
            quicksort(a, j+1, hi);
            hi = j-1;
        }
    }
}

int main()  {
    int len = INT_MAX/2+1;
    printf("New Arr with len = %d\n",len);
    int *arr = malloc(len * sizeof *arr);
    if (!arr) return fprintf(stderr, "allocation failed\n"), EXIT_FAILURE;

    /* populate pessimal array */
    for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
        arr[j] = len-j;
    }

    printf("start sorting\n");
    quicksort(arr, 0, len-1);

    /* test - is it sorted? */
    for (int i = 0;  i+1 < len;  ++i)
        if (arr[i] >= arr[i+1])
            return fprintf(stderr, "not sorted\n"), EXIT_FAILURE;
    free(arr);
}
```

Comment: I think, that the Problem was the recursion depth (which would explain why it doesn’t crash on your system at the same point as on mine) because already only with your implementation of the     quicksort() function, it didn’t crash (tested with  size 200’000)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is too deep to store it on stack.
It has to store `int j = partition(..)` for each level.
There are declarative techniques to minimize recursive stack usage.
For example carrying the results as argument. But this case is far more complicated than I could give an example.